# Mercurial: Did not pull before committing local changes and push. Created 8+ heads

Tags: mercurial, push, pull

I read all the questions suggested while posing, but I just ended up getting confused :S I made a few changes and committed and pushed them. But later I came to know that the repository was pushed to, before I pushed to it. So My questions are:

Q1. Did my pushing overwrite the repository, i.e does the repository no longer have the changes that were pushed before me?

Q2. What should I do in such cases? I need to have the changes that I made, and the other changes too, w/o having to make the other guy pull my code, re-commit, re-push, and I pulling again, just to get the same working copy.

Q3. Is there anyway that the code can be updated/pulled implicitly before I commit/push?

<strike>Q4. What is the rebase option? I read about it on the Documentation, but the changes I perform on the code are not private.</strike>

Assumptions:

1. There aren't any branches created. (Well, they are created, but they are different modules, and I am not concerned with them).
2. I use Eclipse and MercurialEclipse.

EDIT: Sorry if the question is a (possible) duplicate of existing question.

Comment: Did you push with the `-f` flag? If not, then you didn't even create new heads. If you did use it, then you probably should have pulled and merged first. Either way, you can fix it by pulling now, and if there are multiple heads, merging, committing, and then pushing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I manage to create a medusa-repo in hg, I determine which branch is going to be "mainline". Then I go to each sub-branch and perform this process:

```
hg up -r subbranch
hg merge -r mainline-branch
hg commit -m "merged from main"
hg up -r mainline-branch
hg merge -r subranch
hg commit -m "brought in the subchanges from subbranch"
```

By merging to the subbranch first, I make sure that the mainline doesn't get damaged, then I can trivially merge to mainline.

This is not a major crisis; this just requires working with the other developers so you all start hitting the same branch again in the next day or so.

Comment: i went to each head, in a oldest head(revsion) first manner.used a hg up -r <revision> and then did a hg commit --close-branch. any comments on that?

Comment: @Kau - Well, I close off branches when I'm done with them - either by merging their changes in or determining that the approach is fruitless.

Comment: The close-branch option marks that head as inactive. It doesn't do anything with the changes associated with it. Currently your repo may only have one head, but you've abandoned (but not deleted) the changes your colleagues did. You need to do the merge as Paul suggests.

Answer (score 4):

You can't destroy remote changes by pushing. You can create multiple heads with `-f`, but you can't create destroy history just by pushing.

To get a good look at the state of the repository to see what's happened, use `hg serve` and look at it in the browser (probably http://localhost:8000/graph). Then you can see visually what the state of heads and merges is.

Comment: This is the status of my repo: http://i54.tinypic.com/4kk0gw.jpg (YUCK) doing a hg merge tells me that I have 12 heads :( I guess we dont know how to use VCS..

Comment: You need to take care of the heads. First identify if you genuinely require any of the heads as separate heads, or if they are all just variations of the same projects. For instance, one head might be a hotfix to an older release so you might want to keep that head separate. For the rest, you need to merge them, so take two and two heads at a time, update to one, merge with the other, and commit to get rid of one of the heads. Then rinse and repeat until you're back down to the right number of heads. And yes, there seems to be a need for some more learning here.

Comment: If you want, you can visit the Mercurial room on Chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39/mercurial), I'll be there all night (ie. around 5-6 hours more) if you have questions or need some pointers. I'm not saying I'm an expert yet, but I've been down the road you've just discovered so I know the backways back to the main road :)

Comment: Wow - impressive.  Never seen a repository quite like that before :-)  Never mind, you won't do it again. I see you were in the chat, did you get it all fixed up?

Comment: lol, yeah, i will never do it again, cant say the same about the others :) couldnt fix it. i tried to do hg up -r <revision> and then a hg commit --close-branch. it ended up being messier than i started, since essentially i kinda didnt know what i was doing. but starting to use tortoisehg and will hopefully learn from the these mistakes.

Comment: @Kaustubh: you probably want to keep all changes, so update to the main one you want to keep and start merging the others with `hg merge <revision>`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand Mercurial, by default, it's not possible to push when that push would create a new remote head.
In other words: if someone else pushed before you, and you didn't pulled in and *merged* those changes.
This behaviour can be changed however using

```
push -f
```

Did you use that option?

Mr. Spolsky explains it way better in [his tutorial](http://hginit.com/02.html).

Comment: eclipse would tell me to use the -f option, whch we would graciously accept :( rebasing is a better option.

Comment: @Kau: rebase destroys history - not a better option. don't accept things you don't understand!

Comment: @Kau: just to clarify: the hg model is that repo history is immutable. A changeset is always derived from other changesets. A rebase breaks the version-history model hg works on. For some reason, I don't like the idea of having branches 'floating' around in my repo without a specific version they patch. ;)

Comment: i think u mis-interpreted, i meant, we would accept the -f option. i will use the rebase option from now on. We also have only one branch, and I am also going to use branches from now on.

Comment: People aren't misinterpreting. They're saying don't force push, and don't rebase. Merge.

Answer (score 0):

> Q3. Is there anyway that the code can be updated/pulled implicitly
>   before I commit/push?

In the .hg/hgrc, add

```
[hooks]
pre-commit = hg pull -u
```